# Parsing Excel Cell to get info I need

Tags: excel, vba

I am doing a project and currently I am doing it manually, but I think there is a way I can automate this.

My data set looks like this: Each Cell has a city, a state, a zip code (all in the format listed below)

```
Stony Brook, New York 11794-0001 United States
```

I figured out how to pull out the City, but I cant figure out how to pull the state. For single state names I can do it no problem. But for the example up there it only pulls New not new york, since im parsing from the , to the next space. Is there a way I can pull from the , to a number? Using mid maybe. Please let me know, all the data looks like the example I provided. Can't wait to hear back!

Comment: Hi Alex, welcome to StackOverflow! Could you please post the code you're using the extract the City so we can help you debug? Thanks!

Comment: When you state *'all in the format listed below'* you should mean it. Zip and Zip+4 are considered two different formats and compensating for both becomes more complex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find the first digit in the cell,

```
=MIN(SEARCH({0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}, A1&"0123456789"))
```

To extract the name of the state,

```
=MID(A1, SEARCH(",", A1) + 2, MIN(SEARCH({0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}, A1&"0123456789")) - SEARCH(",", A1) - 3)
```

Comment: This is including a leading and trailing space around the state name.

Comment: @dwirony Fixed now.

Comment: Still has a trailing space :p. Sorry to give you a hard time ;)

Comment: I just fixed that a second ago

Comment: Testing on `Stony Brook, New Hampshire 11235`, my `Debug.Print` for the value of the return result is "New Hampshire "

Comment: That should finally do it I think.

Comment: I could have been lazy and just used `TRIM`.   LOL

Comment: I made a VBA solution but it looked so sloppy I'm too ashamed to post it hah

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked perfectly. I had the cell formula for another problem, I just couldn't figure out how to combine it. Thank you again :)

Comment: My pleasure.  When you get enough rep, I would appreciate an upvote.